# Git just wiped out half my local repo, with random things being pulled to my other machine, after adding a .gitignore

Tags: git

EDIT: so there are two possibilities atm:

1. The way I've used wildcards in  the .gitignore file i.e. with a lone parent entry, has revealed unexpected behaviour
2. I was a bad boy and pushed from a machine that hadn't been updated in about two weeks: I run Arch and this is a portable machine so I only use it on adventures. I did do a full system update and it didn't update git so not sure atm.

I am going to test the laptop with a few dummy repos and also try to break git with .gitignore. Will report back in the morning, sleep time now.

SECOND EDIT:

I can't replicate this problem with either an old machine or with a seemingly abnormal .gitignore. The only vague conclusion I can draw, is that somehow my slightly outdated machine caused issues. However, since I can't actually prove this, I can't say for sure. I think this is a case of user error.

ORIGINAL POST:

I've just added a .gitignore file with the following contents

```
build
build/*
CMSIS
CMSIS/*
FreeRTOS
FreeRTOS/*
tags
```

I then pushed the changes and pulled them onto my other laptop. Random things weren't pulled, like half of a file and stuff like that... then I went to look at my makefile and found this:

```
#
# makefile
# <username>, 2019-06-02 16:16
#

all:
     @echo "makefile needs your attention"

#vim: ft=make
#
```

Then when I went to cat the contents to paste it here, the file is now gone. Did I do a stupid or is Git is just in an incoherent state right now?

Also here is my project stucture:

```
$ tree

.
|-- CMSIS
|   `-- efm32zg
|       |-- Source -> /usr/include/sdks/gecko_sdk/platform/Device/SiliconLabs/EFM32ZG/Source
|       `-- system_efm32zg.d
|-- FreeRTOS
|   `-- efm32zg
|       `-- Source -> /usr/include/sdks/gecko_sdk/util/third_party/freertos/Source
|-- README
|-- build
|   |-- debug
|   |   |-- CMSIS
|   |   |   `-- efm32zg
|   |   |       |-- subdir.mk
|   |   |       `-- system_efm32zg.d
|   |   |-- FreeRTOS
|   |   |   `-- efm32zg
|   |   |       `-- subdir.mk
|   |   |-- efm32zg.ld
|   |   |-- makefile
|   |   |-- objects.mk
|   |   `-- sources.mk
|   `-- release
|       |-- STK3200_config.o
|       |-- config_dw1000.o
|       |-- config_efm32zg222f32.o
|       |-- config_example.o
|       |-- config_venus638.o
|       |-- dw1000_adaptor.o
|       |-- dw1000_buildMAC.o
|       |-- dw1000_commRxTx.o
|       |-- dw1000_decodeMAC.o
|       |-- dw1000_nodeMgmt.o
|       |-- dw1000_tofCalcs.o
|       |-- dw1000_types.o
|       |-- efm32zg222f32_adaptor.o
|       |-- efm32zg_cmu_HAL.o
|       |-- efm32zg_gpio_HAL.o
|       |-- efm32zg_gpio_IO_HAL.o
|       |-- efm32zg_interrupts_HAL.o
|       |-- efm32zg_timer_HAL.o
|       |-- efm32zg_types_HAL.o
|       |-- efm32zg_usart_HAL.o
|       |-- efm32zg_usart_IO_HAL.o
|       |-- entertainment_IPS.axf
|       |-- entertainment_IPS.bin
|       |-- entertainment_IPS.hex
|       |-- main.o
|       |-- mpi_cmu.o
|       |-- mpi_ext_dev.o
|       |-- mpi_gpio.o
|       |-- mpi_timer.o
|       |-- mpi_usart.o
|       |-- spongecake.axf
|       |-- spongecake.bin
|       |-- spongecake.hex
|       |-- startup_efm32zg.o
|       |-- system_efm32zg.o
|       |-- venus638.o
|       `-- venus638_adaptor.o
|-- src
|   |-- HAL
|   |   |-- host
|   |   |   `-- efm32zg222f32
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_cmu_HAL.c
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_cmu_HAL.h
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_gpio_HAL.c
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_gpio_HAL.h
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_gpio_IO_HAL.c
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_gpio_IO_HAL.h
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_interrupts_HAL.c
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_interrupts_HAL.h
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_timer_HAL.c
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_timer_HAL.h
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_types_HAL.c
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_types_HAL.h
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_usart_HAL.c
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_usart_HAL.h
|   |   |       |-- efm32zg_usart_IO_HAL.c
|   |   |       `-- efm32zg_usart_IO_HAL.h
|   |   `-- slave
|   |       |-- README
|   |       |-- dw1000
|   |       |   |-- README
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_buildMAC.c
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_buildMAC.h
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_commRxTx.c
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_commRxTx.h
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_decodeMAC.c
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_decodeMAC.h
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_nodeMgmt.c
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_nodeMgmt.h
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_regs.h
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_tofCalcs.c
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_tofCalcs.h
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_types.c
|   |       |   |-- dw1000_types.h
|   |       |   `-- dw1000_version.h
|   |       `-- venus638
|   |           |-- README
|   |           |-- venus638.c
|   |           `-- venus638.h
|   |-- README
|   |-- application
|   |   |-- README
|   |   |-- configs
|   |   |   |-- README
|   |   |   |-- _app_config.h
|   |   |   |-- config_dw1000.c
|   |   |   |-- config_dw1000.h
|   |   |   |-- config_efm32zg222f32.c
|   |   |   |-- config_efm32zg222f32.h
|   |   |   |-- config_example.c
|   |   |   |-- config_example.h
|   |   |   |-- config_venus638.c
|   |   |   `-- config_venus638.h
|   |   `-- main.c
|   |-- board
|   |   |-- README
|   |   `-- STK3200
|   |       |-- STK3200_config.c
|   |       `-- STK3200_config.h
|   |-- middleware
|   |   |-- README
|   |   |-- mpi_cmu.c
|   |   |-- mpi_cmu.h
|   |   |-- mpi_ext_dev.c
|   |   |-- mpi_ext_dev.h
|   |   |-- mpi_gpio.c
|   |   |-- mpi_gpio.h
|   |   |-- mpi_port.h
|   |   |-- mpi_timer.c
|   |   |-- mpi_timer.h
|   |   |-- mpi_types.h
|   |   |-- mpi_usart.c
|   |   `-- mpi_usart.h
|   `-- port_adaptors
|       |-- README
|       |-- dw1000_adaptor.c
|       |-- dw1000_adaptor.h
|       |-- efm32zg222f32_adaptor.c
|       |-- efm32zg222f32_adaptor.h
|       |-- venus638_adaptor.c
|       `-- venus638_adaptor.h
|-- tags
`-- tools
    `-- openocd
        `-- jlink
            `-- openocd.cfg
```

Comment: Is it possible someone intercepted the code between the push/pull? I remember seeing that a few users had been hacked on GitHub

Comment: Yeh totally a possibility. I use a vpn on the machine though, so probably not very likely.

Comment: i would do a `git log —all -p` just to manually check commit history and make sure it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

First, your gitignore could just be:

```
build/
CMSIS/
FreeRTOS/
```

No need for wildcard.

Second, if those folder were already tracked, you need to untrack them.
For instance:

```
git rm --cached -r build/
```

Third, do a `git status` in your original repository to see if any file appears deleted.
Do a git show to see exactly what was recorded in the last commit.

Comment: Ok cool. Would that explain why files in the src/host/efm32zg222f32 folder were half updated when I pulled? Coz that was weird

Comment: @BitShift Not sure: you did not mention in your question exactly what was half updated. But a `git show` will show you what was recorded: you can check if it includes `src/host/efm32zg222f32` files.

Comment: Cool. Yeh everything was updated properly. I add all my files one at a time and do things properly. Sounds like either git is trash now or the .gitignore produced unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @BitShift You can check if a file (that you think should have been tracked, and is missing in your clone) is ignored with `git check-ignore -v local/path/to/file` (local to the repo)

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try the following that will ignore things that have already been committed:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged build/
```